# I can't write unless I execute ctfmon as admin

Tags: windows-10

Well, the other day I installed Windows 10 2004 without Cortana permissions. Now, for some reason, I can't write in the Windows menu nor in the new Windows 10 control panel.

Is there any wat to solve this problem? Maybe creating a script that executes ctfmon at startup?

Comment: Make a new, test, Windows User Account.  See if Cortana works in a new account. Cortana is subject to profile damage.

Comment: I just created a new account I enabled all the options which I'm asked for at the 
 startup process, but I had the same problem.

Comment: If that is the case, and since you just installed Windows 10, it may be best long term to install it again using its default settings.

Comment: I installed it like a week ago and I have lots of configuration and new files. I would like to patch it. Thanks anyway for the suggestion!

Comment: Given that you made configuration changes that damaged Cortana, I am not sure.  Try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link. Use the second choice offered and at the appropriate spot, Keep Everything.  See if that fixes the issue.   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: I updated to 2004. And then, the first LBA of my SSD had errors (using Victoria SSD). Then, I formatted the SSD and then I reinstall my Windows again (using the same pen drive) when I updated from 1809 to 1909 this problem happened again.